# How to detect enter keypress in a form and scroll to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i search something in a select tag and press enter key, the page doesn't scroll to element

I tried .keypress method but i was not able to get it with the next code:

```js
$('#quicksearch-2').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    function pageScroll() {
      var elmnt = document.getElementById("listings");
      elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
});
```

I expect to write a text in the search bar and when press enter key, scroll to an element. Now the search bar works, but not scrolls when i press enter key.

Comment: You are defining a function but not calling it anywhere. You do not need the function... just the code should be sufficient.

Comment: Oh thank you very much Rory! now i tried as you commented and worked fine!

      $('#quicksearch-2').on('keyup', function(e) {

      if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {

      var elmnt = document.getElementById("listings");

      elmnt.scrollIntoView();

      }

    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is not needed unless you plan on calling it on several occasions. This should work for you.

```
  $('#quicksearch-2').on('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
          var elmnt = document.getElementById("listings");
          elmnt.scrollIntoView();
      }
    });
```